# Failed to register sharepoint service

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, configuration-wizard

I changed database server from MyOldDatabase to new server HA (MyNewDatabase1, MyNewDatabase2, VIP 172.27.4.8) by following this [enter link description here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/01/move-sharepoint-databases-to-new-sql-server.html)

Here is my alias

[image]

It's working except my search service. I'm try to fix this issue. And now i get this error :
[image]

Here is the error:

> 12/30/2021 09:03:23 11 ERR Failed to register SharePoint services. An
> exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown. Additional
> exception information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object. at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationAccessor.get_SearchAdminDatabaseSqlSession()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Topology.BaseDao`1.LoadAll(String sqlCommand, Dictionary`2 parameters) at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Topology.SearchTopologyManager.GetActiveTopology(String
> constellationName) at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_ActiveTopology()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.GetLocalSearchComponents(SearchServiceApplication
> application) at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.ThrowIfComponentsRunning()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Unprovision()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRoleManager.<>c_DisplayClass7.b_6()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRoleManager.ConfigureServiceInstance(SPServiceInstance
> serviceInstance) at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerRoleManager.ConfigureServer(Boolean
> throwOnFailure) at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean
> provisionTheServicesToo) at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run() at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Now I cant open SharePoint central admin. Its always return http 500 internal server error.

Any suggestion please....?

Answer (score 0):

**Please perform the following troubleshooting：**

1.In the **Registry Editor**, navigate to the following subkey, and then delete
it: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0\WSS\Services\Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Administration.SearchService`. Then, run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard again.

**Note:** It is recommended that you back up before deleting

2.Enable search admin timer job via powershell:

```
Enable-SPTimerJob job-application-server-admin-service
```

3.Update the account running Osearch15/Hostcontroller services using:

```
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -IgnoreSSLWarnings $true -ServiceAccount <domain\Account> -ServicePassword $password
```

4.Make sure the account you use to configure the application is a member of the **WSS_WPG** group and the group has full control over the following path: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications`

5.Run following powershell to check if AdminComponents has value returned:

```
$sa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication 'Search Service Application'
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent -SearchApplication $sa
```

If not, set as following:

```
$varInstance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -local
set-spenterprisesearchadministrationcomponent –searchapplication $varSearchApp –searchserviceinstance $varInstance
```

**Here is a similar case for your reference:**

- [Failed to register sharepoint service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/678876/failed-to-register-sharepoint-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing SP the the VIP, point it to the AG Listener.